# Page not found after installation of node static

Tags: node.js, node-static

after the installation of node-static in my windows pc with the command:

```
npm install -g node-static
```

When I run the **static.cmd**, it says to me that it listen at **http://127.0.0.1:8080** but when i try this address on my browser, it response always not found instead the **index.html** with the classic hello world.
I don't understand what is the problem.

Thanks in andvace

Answer (score 1):

When you just type http://127.0.0.1:8080 node-static is trying to search for a nameless file so it returns "Not found" but if you will look at the command line while you are performing this request you'll see a 404 request to that empty file.

Just approach a real file in the directory you ran node-static from: http://127.0.0.1:8080/myFile.txt